# Sonarqube: You must install a plugin that supports the language 'css'

Tags: sonarqube, teamcity, sonarqube-scan, gradle-plugin

I have installed Sonarqube 6.7.5 with several plugins, including the [Sonar CSS](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/SonarCSS) plugin version 1.0.2.611.  I ran a scan locally with "publish" mode and everything was good.  But then when I ran a scan as part of a Team City job that ran with "preview" mode, I got this failure:

> You must install a plugin that supports the language 'css'

I have my 6.7.5 version of Sonarqube running, and when I run a build using the new Sonarqube server, I get that message about the "css" language.  None of the Team City build parameters are changing other than the mode--it works when I run in "publish" mode and it gives that error when I run in "preview" mode.  My Team City builds use the Gradle sonar scanner (2.6.2).

I believe I haven't spelled the language name incorrectly. The Sonarqube server shows CSS listed under Quality Profiles, with a default profile set:
[image]
And it shows under the Quality Profile I am using for this project:
[image]

Here's the section from my Gradle build file:

```
sonarModules {
    module {
        name "CSS"
        property "sonar.language", "css"
        property "sonar.projectBaseDir", "."
        property "sonar.sources", "jcr_root/etc/designs"
    }
}
```

What could be causing this issue when I run it via the Team City build?

Comment: I'm not sure where is your problem exactly, but SonarCSS requires SQ 6.7, it should not work with 5.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never did totally figure it out, but here's how I resolved this:

- The CSS plugin I had been using was the one listed on the [Sonarqube plugins list](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/SonarCSS): SonarCSS version 1.0.2.611
- I removed this plugin and instead installed a *different* CSS plugin, the Sonar-css plugin from https://github.com/racodond/sonar-css-plugin/releases (version 4.18)

This different plugin works for me, both for Publish mode and Preview mode.  I presume there is some issue with the module configuration in Preview mode with the plugin that the docs.sonarqube.org site uses.   Maybe this will help someone else!